# Cannot redeclare function error in for each

Tags: php, wordpress, redeclaration

I am attempting to pull information from a custom post, feed it into a foreach loop and then echo it out into a function in repeating panel. At some point I'm guessing the function declaration is being redeclared (it is not in any other file, I'm 100% confident of this) as I keep getting a "Cannot redeclare output_member() previously declared in same file path php 43".

Any help is appreciated.

```
function output_team_members( $title, $id, $position ) {
$post_thumbnail = has_post_thumbnail( $id );
if ( $post_thumbnail == true ) {
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id );
} else {
    $image = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/images/avatar.png';
}
$first = explode( ' ', $title, 2 );
$first_name = $first[0];
$position_title = get_field( 'person_title', $id );
$job_summary = get_field( 'job_summary', $id );
echo
    "<li class='is-active orbit-slide'>
        <figure class='orbit-figure'>
            <div class='top'>
                <h4>Meet $first_name</h4>
                <p>$job_summary</p>
            </div>
            <div class='bottom'>
                <img src=$image>
                <h5>$title</h5>
                <p>$position_title</p>
                <button class='orbit-previous'></button>
                <button class='orbit-next'></button>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>";
}

$team_members = get_posts(
[
    'post_type' => 'team-member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
]
);


/** Grabs information about the post types team-member */
function output_member( $team_members ) {
foreach ( $team_members as $member ) {
    output_team_members( $member->post_title, $member->ID, $member->post_content );
}
}


?>

<div class="orbit">
<div class="orbit-wrapper">
    <div class="orbit-container">
            <?php output_member( $team_members ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. For future devs it was easier to remove the functions all together and just do this

```
$team_members = get_posts(
[
    'post_type' => 'team-member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
]
);

 ?>

<div class="orbit">
<div class="orbit-wrapper">
    <div class="orbit-container" style="height: 500px;">
     <?php
        foreach ( $team_members as $member ) {
        $title   =  $member->post_title;
        $id      = $member->ID;
        $positon = $member->post_content;
        $post_thumbnail = has_post_thumbnail( $id );
        if ( true === $post_thumbnail ) {
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id );
        } else {
            $image = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/images/avatar.png';
        }
        $first          = explode( ' ', $title, 2 );
        $first_name     = $first[0];
        $position_title = get_field( 'person_title', $id );
        $job_summary    = get_field( 'job_summary', $id );
        echo
        "<li class='orbit-slide'>
            <figure class='orbit-figure'>
                <div class='top'>
                    <h4>Meet $first_name</h4>
                    <p>$job_summary</p>
                </div>
                <div class='bottom'>
                    <img src=$image>
                    <h5>$title</h5>
                    <p>$position_title</p>
                </div>
            </figure>
        </li>";
        }
 ?>
                    <button class='orbit-previous'></button>
                    <button class='orbit-next'></button>
    </div>
</div>
```